# A weird result, as a result of this PHP script

Tags: php, variables, get

```
require_once 'include/BestBuy/Service/Remix.php';  

$skuid = rawurldecode($_GET['skuid']);  

$apiKey = 'tfvs7h89pwn4pzmyj9nxemmg'; // Your API key

$remix  = new BestBuy_Service_Remix($apiKey);  

$result = $remix->product('$skuid','json')  
->show(array('url'))  
->query();  

$data = json_decode ($result, true);  

$feed = $data['url'];  

print <<< FEEDS  
$feed  
FEEDS;
```

When I put this script into my page, the $feed will echo the current URL.
But when I manually supply the script with an integer, replacing ($skuid) it will be successful.
It's really weird, But I think it has something to do with me using a variable in that specific array.

And it is also weird, because It was working before I re arranged some of the HTML.

I'm trying to approach this problem the most logical way.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Also, when I say it will echo the 'URL' I am reffering to the current page URL.What I need to do is get a json encoded url from an XML file.

Comment: Try a print_r($_GET) to see the content of your GET-array... is there a (correct) value for the key 'skuid'?

Comment: Yes, skuid is supplied by the database

Comment: The content of the GET-array does not belong to the database but to your request. But never mind :-) Where do you replace the $skuid variable? the invocation of $remix->product can be done without the '' surrounding $skuid.

Comment: The Sku is supplied by the database which is then used to request this PHP script in order to retrieve content based off that (sku) integer. It seems like it is getting cancelled out somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should you have $skuid in quotes? I would expect:

```
$result = $remix->product($skuid,'json')
```

*rather than*

```
$result = $remix->product('$skuid','json')
```